# In a Django ModelForm, I want to display a CharField as a Select Field with defined choices

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to follow the documentation on the Django site to overwrite the default formatting of the form.  I have tried a number of solutions (all commented out and they give me an error).  The non-commented section, works but just renders a select box without any choices.  Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
def get_site_geographies():
    return Site.objects.values_list('site_geography', flat=True).distinct()

class SiteFilterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = ['site_geography', 'site_region', 'site_name']
        # field_classes = {
        #     'site_geography': forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_site_geographies())
        # }
        widgets = {
            'site_geography': forms.Select
        # widgets = {
        #    'site_geography': forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_site_geographies())
        # }
```

In models.py, this is the relevant model field that I am referring to:

```
class Site (models.Model):
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    site_geography = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    site_region = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choices options takes an iterable. A list or tuple of 2-tuples, which would be of the format:

```
(value, value to display)
```

So, you need to iterate over your values and create this format.

Comment: I was able to modify the get_site_geographies function to produce the list of tuples as you recommended; however, the widget = section of the meta still provides the error:  'ChoiceField' object is not callable.  Is there something wrong the with that section?

Comment: Just got it to work now by changing the meta to:  
    
widgets = {
               'site_geography': forms.Select(choices=get_site_geographies())
     }

Thanks so much you solved it for me!